# Psalm 56:8, What Does The Expression Mean: "Put my tears in Your bottle."

Tags: psalms

**Psalm 56:8**

What did David mean by the expression: "Put my tears in Your bottle"

> You have taken account of my wanderings; Put my tears in Your bottle.
>   Are they not in Your book? (NASB)

Answer (score 3):

The Hebrew text of this verse is uncertain.  Jewish scholars have called the Masoretic Text into question.

The Septuagint, based on a much older Hebrew text, reads:

> O God, I have declared my life to thee; thou hast set my tears before thee, even according to thy promise.

Comment: User 33515:I am no textual expert ,most translators use the same expression. The expression "thou hast set my tears before thee" would require the same answer.

Comment: I completely believe it.  The Jewish Publication Society editors list hundreds if not thousands of verses in the Masoretic Text as "*Heb. uncertain*" in their (Jewish) translation, but Christian translations give no indication that there is any uncertainty.  Sometimes it is because there is confusion about how the text should have been vowelized (the original text had no vowels).  The Septuagint is much older than the Masoretic Text; it is always interesting when the Greek Jews of the second century BC seemed to have interpreted the text differently than the European Jews of the Middle Ages.

Comment: Who exactly are the scholars who call the text of this verse uncertain? Please provide citation or references.

Comment: In the context of this verse, *Heb. uncertain* probably means "translation uncertain" rather than "text uncertain." The word ספרה (meaning "book," "count," or with the LXX "promise") appears only in this verse. It doesn't mean the text is necessarily corrupted.

Answer (score 3):

In the MT, the verse in question is numbered as Psalm 56:9 :

> נֹדִי סָפַרְתָּה אָתָּה שִׂימָה דִמְעָתִי בְנֹאדֶךָ הֲלֹא בְּסִפְרָתֶךָ

In transliteration the MT verse is:

> Nodi safarta atah
>   simah dimati b'nodecha
>   ha'lo b'sifratecha

In literal linear translation this is:

> My migrations you have counted
>   put my tears in your waterskin
>   (isn't [it]/aren't [they]) in your book?

An alternate translation for the last line is:

> They are certainly in your book

as the *ha'lo*, "aren't", can be either a rhetorical question implying certainty, or an actual question. The rhetorical usage is more common.

The LXX translated figuratively in many instances. In this instance, it translates *sifratecha*, "your book" as "your promise" similar to the implication of promise in Exodus 32:32 (NIV):

> But now, please forgive their sin--but if not, then blot me out of the book you have written.

Note the alliteration in the MT text, first on the letters *samech* and *sin* (S):

> Nodi **S**afarta atah
>   **S**imah dimati b'nodecha
>   ha'lo b'**S**ifratecha

And the line-end alliteration on "you", *A*, *AH*:

> Nodi safart**A** at**AH**
>   sim**AH** dimati b'nodech**A**
>   ha'lo b'sifratech**A**

The alliteration on the letter *dal* (D):

> No**D**i safarta atah
>   simah **D**imati b'no**D**echa
>   ha'lo b'sifratecha

The play on words between "my migrations", *nodi* and "your waterskin, *nodecha*:

> **Nodi** safarta atah
>   simah dimati b'**nodecha**
>   ha'lo b'sifratecha

And the play on words between "you counted", *safarta* and "your book", *sifratecha":

> Nodi **safarta** atah
>   simah dimati b'nodecha
>   ha'lo b'**sifratecha**

The waterskin or bottle in the second line is an allusion to the desert wanderings of the supplicant in the first line.

Taking all of these alliterations, allusions and word plays into account makes argument for uncertainty in the text difficult. It is just too neatly constructed to be corrupted.

The supplicant is asking God to count the tears of his tribulations and save them in a jar. That is to remember them in order to give the supplicant just compensation in due time, or to keep them on account to offset the supplicant's transgressions.

Comment: I agree with you last paragraph  "The Lord is near to the brokenhearted  And saves those who are crushed in spirit."Psalm  48:18 Young David composed this psalm 56  while running from murderous King Saul. David escaped to Gath, but he feared capture when he was recognized by the Philistines.

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering if we may not unite in consideration this plea of the Psalmist that God should place the tears of the Faithful into a bottle with the scene in Rev.5:9 of the opening of the fifth seal, when the Martyrs are exposed under the Altar, beseeching God to vindicate their blood upon the inhabitants of the earth.  The combining element is that sequence of Seven Angels which are given vials (bottles) by which they pour out upon the earth the seven last plagues (Rev. 15).  Could not these vials contain the tears of the Martyrs whose sorrows now overflow the consciences of the impious to the effect that they "drink the blood that they have shed"? (Rev. 16:6).  If blood-letting is in analogy to guilt, the tears the impious drink from these vials may represent their own guilt for these tears  by which they are confounded and perish in denial.  Referring back to the Altar, we see in v.7 of the Vulgate  "...et audivi altare dicens etiam Domine Deus Omnipotens vera et justa judicia tua." which may be translated: "And now too I heard the altar speaking , Lord God Omnipotent, true and just are your judgments."  Is this voice of the altar referring back to the Martyrs waiting there who have long sought this justice of God?   The description of each of the seven last plagues, if carefully worked out, can well lend itself to this possibility as one aspect of a complex interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Means .God will blot them off our land .and The Covenant will be fulfilled as Esau and Ishmael had no mercy an there names be removed from the book of life ..ISAACS People the end of Esau and Ishmael and Isaac's beginning... Tribe of Reuben.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX, Debbie, so glad to have you with us. Please take the tour to get yourself familiar with the site. Enjoy ! hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour